# My Professor changed my multiple choice answers. What should I do?

Tags: ethics, grades

My prof changed some of my multiple choice answers on a test to give me a better grade. I noticed because I remember putting different answers for the questions and the way they were circled was not like how I write. I would have passed the test anyway, so I am not sure why they would have done this. I feel guilty because I want my grades to be based on my own merits. But this test was not a case where the prof raises a student mark because they deserved it based on effort. They deliberately changed my incorrect answers to give me a better mark on a test that I already did okay on. What should I do if anything?

Comment: I would check the facts - that the professor indeed changed your answers - because the situation sounds incredible enough that it's hard to believe. A possible explanation, for example, could be that the professor confused your answer script with another student's answer script.

Comment: I don't think so, they gave us back the tests and the answer booklet was mine

Comment: Still sounds incredible - reminds me of a movie I once watched where the protagonist's boyfriend sneaks into the professor's room to change her answers so she'll pass instead of fail. I'd suggest mentioning to the professor that the answers on the script aren't the ones you marked, the security might have been compromised.

Comment: Why do you think they would do it? Can you imagine a motive?

Comment: No, I am not sure why, especially because I would have still done fine on the test, just not great.

Comment: Really, that does not make sense then. Unless there is something you suspect is intentionally going on (antagonistic or in your favour), I would really subscribe to the idea that there was some mistake here. One more thing to consider is: Does the prof have bad failure rates?

Comment: I don't think they have bad failure rates, but they are known for giving students unfair final course marks (better or worse) for no real ryhme or reason, maybe because the student shows up to class more often. But to me this is on another level if true.

Comment: Is there some reason that they would want you to think you "owe" them something for a favor given. Lots of nasty scenarios come to mind.

Comment: Is there any chance there is something wrong with those questions? Could there have been an announcement that the Prof felt that the questions were unanswerable based on their teaching and thus gave everyone marks for them? Seems a stretch, but I am just trying to find an explanation here. Have you discussed this with any of your fellow students?

Answer (score 3):

This is really tough to approach. On the one hand, it’s incredibly hard to prove this (also since there’s no clear incentive for the professor to do this). On the other hand, you stand to lose a lot if you’re wrong.

That said, paraphrasing Hanlon’s Razor: Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by incompetence.

Your professor might have mixed up something, or accidentally erased your answers (and then wanted to err on your side). You can simply approach them and nicely ask about question 17, that you distinctly remember putting another answer, but you could be wrong etc.